# Div alignment best practice

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently building an example site to follow what I have learned in bootstrap (or what I think I have learned). On this website, I want to align a DIV in a certain position. The Website is NOT adjusted for mobile yet because I am only testing it on my computer at the time.

Is the following code best practice as far as positioning the H1 & H2? I have tried for about 3 hours to position the `div id="outer"` vertically & horizontally centered, to no avail. Frustrated, I turned to `position: absolute` to use `top` and `left` specs. With the code that I provided, is this best practice, AKA the best solution to align these header texts ? BIG thank you in advance (sorry for NOOBing):

https://jsfiddle.net/8kqxtvn8/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -15px;
  width: 50px;
}

.nav-link {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.maincontent {
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: url('img/bgcover.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

#vertical {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 15%;
}

#outer {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Galaxies</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Telescopes</a>
      <div class="logo">
        <a class="navbar-brand custom-logo" href="#"><img src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2016/07/11/794282_education_512x512.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Get involved</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>

<section class="maincontent">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="vertical">
      <div id="outer">
        <h1>Welcome to <span class="LogoTitle">TITLE!</span></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum bla bla bla i dont know bootstrap</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you explain the `link` replacement of the bootstrap CSS with the `import` ? I took this from the developer's site

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use absolute, (absolute element are ignored by other element and ignoring other element)

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
 background-color: transparent;
 background: transparent;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 0;
 display: flex;
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 font-size: 28px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
 height: auto; 
 margin-top: -20px;
 width: 50px; 
}

.nav-link {
 margin-right: 2rem;
}

.maincontent {
 background-color: grey;
 background-image: url('img/bgcover.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
}

#vertical {
 margin-top: 45px;
}

#outer {
 background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <nav class="nav">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Galaxies</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Telescopes</a>
      <div class="logo">
   <a class="navbar-brand custom-logo" href="#"><img src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2016/07/11/794282_education_512x512.png" /></a>
  </div>    
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Get involved</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>

<section class="maincontent">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="vertical">
   <div id="outer">
    <h1>Welcome to <span class="LogoTitle">TITLE!</span></h1>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum bla bla bla i dont know bootstrap</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I probably don't want to use Pixels if I am trying to position the H1 & H2 somewhere in the center of the page...

Comment: @Helle you want to place them in the middle of the page?

Comment: give or take. The way i have it not is about 30% from the top, and 15% from the left. I have it that way based on a full height/width background image, and the image contents thereof. It looks the best

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to your problem. First up to center the h1 and h2 tags, just add a style `text-align: center` to these elements. 
While the absolute position method still works, you may want to try `margin-top` or `padding-top` to see where you want your element to be placed vertically.

The best approach would be to give your nav a `height` first, and then build sections and containers classes and give them basic styles for things like width, height,padding, margin.

Comment: Since i eventually want to make the site responsive, wouldn't I want to refrain from adding too many heights & widths? Seems like extra work to go and specify @media queries when it gets there.

Also, I am trying to position my H1 & H2 not centered anymore, but rather customized a little to the right, and about half way down. Seems like the numbers for margin or padding would be gigantic. How would mobile react ?

Comment: Even using the percentage wouldn't guarantee that you will be safe from using media queries. One thing you should be looking at ways to add too many nested elements.